# How can I delete multiple accounts in a batch in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash

How can I delete multiple accounts from a batch in GnuCash?
I want to delete several accounts that I created to run some tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete multiple transactions at once in GnuCash?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/91861/how-to-delete-multiple-transactions-at-once-in-gnucash)

Comment: No. I want to delete accounts, not transactions.